# Where to put SQLite database file in Azure App Service?

Tags: database, sqlite, azure, azure-web-app-service

**Q1**: Where do you think is the right place to put a **SQLite** database file (`database.sqlite`) in **Azure Web App** file system? For example:

1. `D:\home\data\database.sqlite`
2. `D:\home\site\database.sqlite`
3. `D:\home\site\wwwroot\database.sqlite`
4. other?

**Q2**: What else should be taken into consideration in order to make sure that the database file won't be accessible to public users as well as not being accidentally overwritten during deployments or when the app is scaled up/down? (The Web App is configured for deployments from a Local Git Repository)

**Q3**: Where to learn more about the file system used in Azure App Service, the official source URL? E.g. how it's shared between multiple VMs within a single Web App, how does it work when the App is scaled up/down, what's the difference between `D:\home` (persistent) vs `D:\local` (non-persistent)...

Note that **SQLite** does not work in **Azure Blob Storage**, so that one is not an option. Please, don't suggest alternative storage solutions, this question is specifically about **SQLite**.

#### References

- [Appropriate Uses For SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/whentouse.html)

Comment: Q1) Options 2 and 3 are the same Q3) Is offtopic

Comment: Q3 only `Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.`

Comment: @lad2025 this question is not about personal opinions, it's directly related to how Azure App Service operates, in what location the file will most likely be overwritten during deployments or scaling up/down.. and in what location it will be safe.

Comment: `recommend ... tutorial or other off-site resource`

Comment: @lad2025 this question cannot be answered without the proof (the original resource of the info provided in the answer).

Answer (score 19):

In a Web App, your app is deployed to `d:\home\site\wwwroot`. This is the area where you may write files. As an example, the `ghost` deployment writes its SQLite database to `d:\home\site\wwwroot\content\data\ghost.db.` (easy to see this, if you open up the kudu console via `yourapp.scm.azurewebsites.net`):

[image: kudu sqlite example]

This file area is shared amongst your web app instances. Similar to an SMB file share, but specific to web apps (and different than Azure's File Service).

The content under `wwwroot` is durable, unless you delete your app service. Scaling up/down impacts the amount of space available. (I have no idea what happens if you scale *down* and the smaller size has less disk space than what you're consuming already).

Comment: What if your app will be scaled to use few machines? Wouldn't that create several sqlite databases?

Comment: @titol - no: Instances of the Web App have a shared storage area. In this case, they'd all be referencing the same database. This isn't the same as storing data in instance-specific storage.

Comment: Azure App Service's [Run From Package functionality](https://github.com/Azure/app-service-announcements/issues/84) specifically states that your site files within wwwroot become _read-only_ (see the limitations section in the link). Run From Package is the default for deployments to Linux machines. If you need _read-write_ access to your sqlite database, save the database file in another directory within `home`, eg for the URI in Python, you can use: `sqlite:////home/instance/database.db`

Comment: @Skeve - at the time I posted my answer (over 7 years ago), Linux-based App Service didn't exist. Probably best for you to post a new answer.

Answer (score 0):

I would say the best location would be app_data folder in the site/wwwroot folder. Create the folder if it doesn't exist.

Comment: For .NET app yes. But in my case, I have a Node.js app and having `app_data` folder might be confusing.

Comment: It might be confusing but will serve the purpose that you are looking for :-)

Answer (score -2):

Web Apps can connect to storage accounts so you can in fact use blob storage and connect that to your web app. So in terms of learning more about it then you need to be looking at the appropriate page of [documentation](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/storage-introduction/#blob-storage).

In your Web App settings you can then select which storage account to use. You can find this under Settings > Data Connections where you can select Storage from the drop down box.

Comment: You cannot connect an Azure disk to a web app (so there's no way to store SQLite directly in a blob).

Comment: You can, I tested it before I posted. But you cannot store SQLite in a blob.

Comment: No, I mean you cannot attach a page blob as a disk in a web app. Yes, you can access storage. But that's not the same thing.

Comment: Ah yes yes, apologies, misunderstood.