# How to access DLLs in a PaaS WebApp?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I would like to run ILSpy on one of my DLLs to verify code is running on a deployment slot and unable to figure out how to retrieve the DLLs from my PaaS WebApp.

Comment: Did you check Kudu Console: https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Kudu-console

Comment: Not exactly sure what you're asking, but all of your files are deployed under `d:\home`, and you can view them via kudu. See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37323377/272109) for a bit more info about where deployed files go, and viewing them.

Comment: Beside using the Kudu console, you can download your DLL using FTP.

Comment: Thank you for the responses. I didn't realize I could get to the files w/ Kudu. Will also give Kudu Console a try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As all mentioned above, If we want to get the published files from the Azure WebApp, we could use the [Kudu tool](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Kudu-console) to do that easily.

More info about Azure website file structure, we could refer to this [document](http://Mhttps://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/File-structure-on-azure). If you want to know more about Azure WebApp, you could refer to Azure [WebApp Sandbox](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-Web-App-sandbox).