# System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteException: unable to open database file

Tags: c#, sqlite, webforms

I have created a SQLite db. It is stored on the C: of my machine.

My application connects to the db ok when running in Local Host. However, when I deploy the Web App to Azure then it fails to connect the database.

I have installed the SQLite Nuget package. I have tested this in local host and it works.

Web Config Connection String:

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="Testdb" connectionString="Data Source=C:\TestSQLite\Testdb.db;Version=3;" providerName="System.Data.SqlLite"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

Web Form Data Source:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="Testdb" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:Testdb %>" ProviderName="System.Data.SQLite" SelectCommand="select * from BatchNumbers" runat="server">
```

I expect the web form to display information stored in the SQLite database table 'BatchNumbers'

And here is the Error Message:

```
[SQLiteException (0xe): unable to open database file]
   System.Data.SQLite.SQLite3.Open(String strFilename, String vfsName, SQLiteConnectionFlags connectionFlags, SQLiteOpenFlagsEnum openFlags, Int32 maxPoolSize, Boolean usePool) +644
   System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConnection.Open() +5579
   HTML5OfflineApplication.BulkCopy_DataTableToSQLLite.Button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Users\Me\OneDrive - Me\Visual Studio\source\repos\Offline\Offline\Secure\BulkCopy_DataTableToSQLLite.aspx.cs:32
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e) +109
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +108
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +12
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument) +15
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData) +31
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +3470
```

I have amended the connection string and tried the following:

```
sql_con = new SQLiteConnection(a, true);
```

and also

```
 connectionString="Data source=C:\TestSQLite\Testdb.db; Version=3; FailIfMissing=False"
```

I think my error is in the event args here which references a specific location on my device that isn't accessible to the program:

```
HTML5OfflineApplication.BulkCopy_DataTableToSQLLite.Button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Users\Me\OneDrive - Me\Visual Studio\source\repos\Offline\Offline\Secure\BulkCopy_DataTableToSQLLite.aspx.cs:32
```

Is it this that is causing the conflict??
 Help!! Arggghe
    enter code here

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where to put SQLite database file in Azure App Service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37317754/where-to-put-sqlite-database-file-in-azure-app-service)

Comment: Hi thanks for this. I have read through the link and I cant see how it helps me. My DB file is on the user device. And my web app accesses data from that location. Seems to be a problem specific to the connection string and/or permissions. What I cant understand is why it works in local host but not live.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding to your comment you want to store the database on the users PC - you cannot open files from the user device without the user actually uploading/selecting it explicitly. You need to either store a user-specific database on your server to access it in the code behind or use something client-side like the browsers localStorage with client-side JavaScript. Being able to access files on the users computer from a web application would be a huge security issue.

Another option would be creating a client-side application instead of a web application.

Comment: Hi thanks (or not !!! ha!) for the advice. Up to now I have focused on web apps. So I could create a windows app instead to manage the problem. Can you suggest a tutorial or learning resource - I have never built a windows app before.

Comment: If you want to create a native Windows app, have a look [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/getting-started/walkthrough-my-first-wpf-desktop-application).